# Hide responsive datatable rows from left to right

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am working on an AngularJS solution and I am using [datatables library](https://datatables.net/) to create responsive tables; Some of them should be displayed in Arabic, so when responsive columns must be hidden from left to right; How can I make that?

Below is my code:

```
<table  datatable="ng" dt-options="vmAR.dtOptions" id="TableAR" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>العمود 1</th>
           <th>العمود 2</th>
           <th>العمود 3</th>
           <th  ng-hide="true">test</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="object in List">
         <td>{{object.param1}}</td>
         <td ng-if="object.param2== '' " ng-bind="object.param3"></td>
         <td ng-if="object.param2!= '' " ng-bind="object.param2"></td>
         <td>{{object.param4}}</td>
         <td ng-hide="true">{{object.param5}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.vmAR.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                    .withOption('paging', false)
                    .withOption('ordering', false)
                    .withOption('info', false)
                    .withOption('responsive', true);
```

Based on [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority), I have tried the below, but nothing worked, it is still hiding columns from right to left:

```
$scope.vmAR.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                    //.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                    .withOption('paging', false)
                    .withOption('ordering', false)
                    .withOption('info', false)
                    .withOption('responsive', true)
                    .withOption('columnDefs', [
                        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: -1 }
                    ]);
```

Any suggestion?

**Update:**

Even with the below code it didn't work:

```
$scope.vmAR.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                    //.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                    .withOption('paging', false)
                    .withOption('ordering', false)
                    .withOption('info', false)
                    .withOption('responsive', true)
                    .withOption('columns', [
                        { responsivePriority: 3 },
                        { responsivePriority: 2 },
                        { responsivePriority: 1 },
                        { responsivePriority: 1 }
                    ]);
```

Comment: You'll probably need to watch the language/locale settings and when they change rebuild the dtOptions with the appropriate priorities.   English = [1,1,2,3,4] and Arabic = [4,3,2,1,1] for your columnDef responsive priority values.

Comment: @kendavidson thank you for your reply, please check the updates

Comment: I have to admit I've never used the angular-datatables, so I can't give much info on how DTOptionsBuilder works - looking at the docs it really depends on what version of the library you're using (to DTColumnBuilder or not to DTColumnBuilder).   The docs aren't too clear with regards to how it uses the columns options, you may want to try 'columnDefs' though as there are examples with changing those.